# Setting a property in a class method in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

this is my first Objective C project, and I'm having trouble setting a property from a class method that also creates the object.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Alphabet.h"
@interface Cipher : NSObject
// Properties that define a filename, a key and an Alphabet object
@property NSString *key;
@property (strong) Alphabet * alphabet;

// This method is a class/factory method to create a Cipher object with the key
+ (id)cipherWithKey:(NSString *) key;

// The following methods encrypt and decrypt a message with the "alphabet"
- (NSString *) decryptWithDefaultAlphabet:(NSString *) message;
- (NSString *) encryptWithDefaultAlphabet: (NSString *) message;
@end
```

I've tried a few different things that haven't worked.

```
#import "Cipher.h"

@implementation Cipher

@synthesize key = _key;
@synthesize alphabet = _alphabet;

+ (id) cipherWithKey : (NSString *) key {
//    self.key = key;
    [Cipher setKey : key];
    return self;
}

+ (void) setKey : (NSString *) key {
    self.key = key;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class "factory" method is incorrect. It needs to create a new instance of the `Cipher` using `alloc`/`init`, then set its key, and finally return the newly created instance:

```
+ (id) cipherWithKey : (NSString *) key {
    Cipher *res = [[Cipher alloc] init];
    [res setKey : key];
    return res; // Return the newly created object, not self (which is a Class)
}
```

When you create a factory method like that, it is common to define a matching `init` method, like this:

```
-(id)initWithKey:(NSString *) key {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _key = key;
    }
    return self;
}
+ (id) cipherWithKey : (NSString *) key {
    return [[Cipher alloc] initWithKey:key];
}
```